# How to make pdf.js work with ie10?

Tags: c#, javascript, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows 8 store app and using XAML/C# to build a E-Book manager where one function of the app is to view pdf files. Since there is no direct API provided by Microsoft, I am trying to view pdf files in webview (by using js) which is by default IE10 and is unchangeable. I would like to know if is there any way of getting through and rendering pdf files in my app?

Also, if there are any alternative approaches to using webview this information would also be  welcomed.

Comment: There are lots of ways to generate PDFs in c#.  Have you looked at Aspose PDF?  That software is not opensource but I am sure there are opensource projects, too.  Have you googled?

Comment: yeah there are many ways to render pdf in c# with wpf and windows forms but when it comes to windows 8 apps its tough that we can include third party assemblies which support rendering.

Comment: May I ask, why even create pdfs for use on a mobile app?  Why not just create a mobile interface for your information?  You can still fire off a command to a web service to generate the pdf and email it to the user if you want.